# TFS BUILD 2010: XAML: how to make double quotes within a double quotes

Tags: xaml, workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

```
[String.Format(&quot;/build Debug "{0}\Sources\Source\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.Interface\Infrastructure.Interface.csproj"&quot;, BuildDirectory)]
```

Say I want to have another double quotes from ===> {0}\Sources\Source\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.Interface\Infrastructure.Interface.csproj <===, but it can only allow once `&quot;` within the String.Format()... What should I do?

I tried => \", @" they are not working at all...

===

If I tried => """ <==

this is what I got:

> The build process failed validation. Details:  Validation Error: The
>   private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the
>   following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing
>   expression "String.Format("/build Debug
>   """{0}\Sources\Company.GOF.Win\Company.GOF.Win.Interface\Company.GOF.Win.Interface.csproj"""",
>   BuildDirectory)". Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation
>   expected.  Validation Error: The private implementation of activity
>   '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler
>   error(s) encountered processing expression "String.Format("/build
>   Debug
>   """{0}\Sources\Source\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.Interface\Infrastructure.Interface.csproj"""",
>   BuildDirectory)". Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation
>   expected.  Validation Error: The private implementation of activity
>   '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler
>   error(s) encountered processing expression "String.Format("/build
>   Debug
>   """{0}\Sources\Services\Services.Interface\Company.GOF.Win.Services.Interface.csproj"""",
>   BuildDirectory)". Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation
>   expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get what you need with

```
"""{0}\Sources\Source\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.Interface\Infrastructure.Interface.csproj"""
```

---

**EDIT**
Judging from your output you have set a:

```
String.Format("/build Debug """{0}\Sources\Company.GOF.Win\Company.GOF.Win.Interface\Company.GOF.Win.Interface.csproj"""", BuildDirectory)
```

It's reasonable this fails.
This should work though:

```
String.Format("/build Debug ""{0}\Sources\Company.GOF.Win\Company.GOF.Win.Interface\Company.GOF.Win.Interface.csproj"""", BuildDirectory)
```

(The only difference is `""{0}\Sources\` instead of `"""{0}\Sources`)